# Java - Count number of symbols in string

Tags: java

Let's say I have this string:

```
String helloWorld = "One,Two,Three,Four!";
```

How can I make it so it counts the number of commas in `String helloWorld`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

the simplest way would be iterate through the String and count them.

```
int commas = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < helloWorld.length(); i++) {
    if(helloWorld.charAt(i) == ',') commas++;
}

System.out.println(helloWorld + " has " + commas + " commas!");
```

Comment: You, sir, are a hero. Thanks.

Comment: @Jahkr thanks, although I wouldn't consider this heroic by any means! :-)

Answer (score 10):

```
int numberOfCommas = helloWorld .replaceAll("[^,]","").length();
```

More implementation you can find in [this site](http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Count_the_number_of_occurrences_of_a_specific_character_in_a_string)

Answer (score 4):

```
String[] tokens = helloWorld.split(",");
System.out.println("Number of commas: " + (tokens.length - 1));
```

Comment: This is not very helpful. Suppose the string is `"One, Two, Thre,,,,"` split won't count the las commas. As the javadoc of the class String says **Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.**

Answer (score 1):

Not so simple but shorter way

```
String str = "One,Two,Three,Four!";  
int num = str.replaceAll("[^,]","").length();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can import com.lakota.utils.StringUtils
then it's so simple.
Import this> import com.lakota.utils.StringUtils;

```
int count = StringUtils.countMatches("One,Two,Three,Four!", ",");
System.out.println("total comma "+ count);
```

Comment: "com.lakota.utils.StringUtils"?

Comment: In order to import something you need to install it first. -1

Comment: You must have able to import the StringUtils from lakota.

Comment: another implementation can be imported from `import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;`

Answer (score 0):

Using StringUtils:

```
int count = StringUtils.countMatches("elephant", "e");
assertEquals(2, count);
```

Using Java 8:

```
String someString = "elephant";
long count = someString.chars().filter(ch -> ch == 'e').count();
assertEquals(2, count);

long count2 = someString.codePoints().filter(ch -> ch == 'e').count();
assertEquals(2, count2);
```